# how to pack and unpack data using python 2.5

Tags: python, python-2.5

I know there are mutliple questions relating to my question but i'm having difficulty understating how pack & unpack works.

for example using `struct.pack("!B",14)` gives me value of `x0e` basically this is a one-byte binary.

how can i create a four-byte binary? for example `struct.pack("!B",104277)` should generate `0x00019755` but i cannot get this code `struct.pack("!B",104277)` to output `0x00019755`

**Background details of my problem**

I'm trying to create a "Type-4 High-resolution grayscale fingerprint image" record which is part of the NIST standard. The first value of Type-4 record is Length of the record (LEN) in this case its 104277 bits, but the standard specifies that the LEN should be represented as four-byte binary. The sample data I have contains this value `0x00019755` which already has been converted to four-byte binary thus complies with standard.

reference links:

- http://code.beckjohnson.com/NistRecordTypes.html
- http://www.nist.gov/itl/csd/biometrics/ansi-nist.cfm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As specified in [§7.3.2.2. Format Characters](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) of the Python manual, the format code for an unsigned 4-byte long is `L`.

```
struct.pack("!L", 104277)
```

Comment: thanks for kindly getting back to me. I was using the local Python Library Reference (Python 2.5 Documentation) and it didnt have the "Standard size" column which is in the link you supplied. Anyway thanks i will try this, I'm sure it will work.